# Playing media opens Apple Music icon on Menu Bar and small controller panel in menu bar

Tags: macos, music.app, vlc, monterey

Playing media files such as videos in, for example, VLC player triggers a music.app icon to appear on the Menu Bar, with a small control panel (play and skip controls). Apple Music itself does not open.

The icon now appears to be permanent since updating to Monterey.

Can anyone tell me what's going on? And how I can disable this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the "Now Playing" menulet which is part of Control Center in Monterey. You can disable it in System Preferences -> Dock & Menu Bar.

[image]